# Bootstrap form groups and jquery tag manager: position tags below the input box?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and [jquery tag manager](https://github.com/max-favilli/tagmanager). Is there any way to control where the tags get populated, relative to the input field? For example, using the below, tags are positioned above the text box.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagmanager/3.0.2/tagmanager.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagmanager/3.0.2/tagmanager.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="form">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control tm-input"/>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tm-input').tagsManager();
});
</script>
```

I don't really like the current setup as it changes the positioning of the text box (moves it down). Rather than populating the tags above the input box, is there any way to populated them below it?

What I'm looking for is something similar to the Stackoverflow tag input field -- tags are displayed *below* the text entry field.

Comment: try to give `tags` `margin-top` same as `input` height in css

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edit some code and then its show below the input

**html**:

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label>Tags</label>
    <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control tm-input"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 tags-show">

  </div>
</div>
```

and **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tm-input').tagsManager({
    tagsContainer: '.tags-show',
  });
});
```